# Infinite refresh - Getting Started with the Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I made the example in http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started, and it works.
But the javascript is constantly executing, so he's constantly do a post on the server..
Always invoke the handler who Redirect to About.aspx and codebehind read the name, ID and other user information.

> form.setAttribute("action", '/FacebookLogin.ashx');

In my MasterPage I have the < div id="fb-root"> and the script code right after the tag < body> (inside the body).
And in my Default.aspx I have the button to LogIn.

Can you help me?

Comment: did you resolve the issue? I'm having the same and is has nothing to do with chrome or IIS cookies thing.

Comment: same problem here, redirecting back from ashx and the script runs over and over, infinite loop - any suggestions solving this without sessionvars?

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue as well from following the example and my issue turned out to be that on my FacebookLogin.ashx handler page, I was redirecting back to my original aspx page, which holds my JavaScript code. Upon entering this code, the JavaScript was executing my authentication again and hence putting me in an infinite loop.

What I ended up doing was grabbing a copy of some JavaScript that gives you persistent session variables in JavaScript from [here](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html). And placing a condition around the code that submits the Post. This way I only hit the FacebookLogin.ashx handler once and doesn't throw me in the loop.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                if (sessvars.fbauthenticated == undefined) {
                    sessvars.fbauthenticated = "1";

                    // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                    // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                    var form = document.createElement("form");
                    form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                    form.setAttribute("action", '/FacebookLogin.ashx');

                    var field = document.createElement("input");
                    field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                    field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
                    field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                    form.appendChild(field);

                    document.body.appendChild(form);
                    form.submit();
                }

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            }
        });
```

Where the conditional line of *if (sessvars.fbauthenticated == undefined) {* keeps my code from posting multiple times to the server.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

change your AppId to the actual facebook app id , which you get once you register your application

```
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
```

//that should solve ur issue

Comment: ? of course I did it --' the problem is because javascript invoke this infinitly! so he's constantly redirect my page to my handler
>FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
>if (response.status === 'connected') .........

Answer (score 0):

On another demo [here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website%20%28With%20Javascript%20SDK%29&ANCHOR) some folks said it was a problem with ie9/chrome and cookies on localhost. Pointing to 127.0.0.1 and run it on iis it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Instead of browsing to http://localhost/MyApp just browse to http://127.0.0.1/MyApp 127.0.0.1 is a loopback address that just points to localhost but doesn't have the special handling of cookies in IE9 and Chrome.