# How to make HTTP POST facebook authentication

Tags: oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

I need some help to implement facebook authentication. I'm doing this sample:
http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started
and it works fine, I can get the access token and get user's info. 
But my problem is because javascript start a loop of http post's, because he's executing the javascript who invokes the handler, so infitly redirect for my page.

So I have Main.aspx and is there where I have the javascript implemented and all my main content, if my handlrer redirect to Main.aspx he enter in loop, if I redirect the handler to SecondPage.aspx he stops the loop, but if i click go back to Main.aspx(or someone else where i've the javascript) he redirect to second...

Comment: It's really not clear what your problem is here, are you sure the loop isn't in your own code because you have a block like 'if (logged in user) then redirect, else, send to login page' and are failing to detect the login?

Answer (score 0):

The issues is that you are redirecting back to your original page from your ashx handler page and when you do that your JavaScript is executing again and hence submitting another Post to the server which in turn calls your ashx handler page again. So you end up in an infinite loop. But when you redirect to a different page from your ashx handler page then the JavaScript that authenticates your user does not execute and does not send another Post.

I ran into this same problem myself and came up with a fairly simple solution which I posted on a different thread dealing with the same issue. you can find the answer on [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898862/infinite-refresh-getting-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk)

On a side note, I continued to research this and found a great solution that allows me to do this all server side instead of using the JavaScript SDK, so I'm not sure it would be of interested to you since your post was about "How to make HTTP POST facebook authentication" but in case you are, the link gives a solution dealing with an ASP.NET app that is not written using MVC. [Getting Started With The Facebook C# SDK](http://multitiered.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/getting-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/)